# Rendering 2 navbar

Tags: reactjs

noob question but I wanted to ask if I am creating a react app that has a front-end and back-end interface. How would I add a navbar for each of them. I am thinking of creating a private route for the backend interface and then adding my navbar there, But navbar on App.JS would clash with that. Am I right to think that, if so how can I fix it?

Comment: React is a front-end library. Your frontend communicates with the backend through rest API, retrieve data, and display it on the front.

Comment: @Medi ye I've got the rest API, retrieving data, and displaying it in tables. It just when I try to add a 2nd navbar for my backend dashboard, it goes on top of my current one :(

Comment: Try to do conditional rendering based on your route. Check [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation). and based on your location render the right navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
function Users() {
  let location = useLocation();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
     {location.pathname === "/backend-navbar"?
     <p>back-end navbar</p> : <p>front-end navar</p>}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I use this method, Navbar from the front end wouldn't apply to '/backend-navbar', right?